# Tableau Reporting on Large SharePoint List

Tags: sharepoint, tableau-api

We plan to set up an application using Tableau to report against data persisted in SharePoint Online lists, some of which will be way larger than the 5000 item list threshold (up to 1.2 million items in one of the lists). Can Tableau efficiently report against large SharePoint lists like this or will the data have to be exported first? Any other best practice recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

There are some SharePoint drivers you can try (see http://tableau.com/support/drivers), but I recommend mirroring your data in a real database and reporting from there.

If you can't use a relational database, then I'd set up a regular automated export process, and then use something like a Tableau Prep flow to create a mirror in a Tableau hyper extract.

SharePoint makes it easy to create a list with little up-front design, but the results often don't have the structural integrity that a relational database enforces - making analysis complicated. Be especially on the lookout for the strange way that SharePoint represents many-to-many relationships. You'll want to convert those to something more traditional for analysis if you are doing anything substantial with those many-to-many associations.